# Oracle Error - Failed: no ocijdbc19 in java.library.path

Tags: jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, java.library.path

I have a PC with many connections, all runs correctly.
I received a new PC Win 10, I work via Cisco Any Connect from home.
I install SQL Developer 20.2 and 19.4 (same version of my old PC), I import my connections (about 15), only 2 connections send me "Success" during a test, all the others give me this error:

***Failed: no ocijdbc19 in java.library.path***

I install also PostgreSQL jdbc and the server is connected correctly.
The difference between the two PC is that in my old PC I had also installed XE and some odbc drivers to use with others products.

Thanks

Comment: something with your connection is setup such to require the Oracle Client - hence the ocijdbc19 message. Show us your connection properties/ensure that you don't have 'Use OCI' enabled in advanced preferences, or install 19c Client, and configure preferences appropriately.

Comment: Indeed. The set-up must, by accident or design, be trying to use the OCI driver. There's almost no good reason to do that with a Java application, although there might have been back in the Oracle 9i days. If you're using the ojdbcXXX.jar Java driver, it won't normally try to load the OCI driver.

Comment: Hello Jeff and Kevin,

The IT department don't write my user/new PC in the group that can use the servers, only this stupid thing.

Thanks for the help.